# Undefined column problem while reshaping data with R

Tags: r, reshape

I am a beginner in R, and for an academic course, I need to reshape a data frame into long format (panel data). My data frame is composed of 65 columns, 61 of them are Years from 1960 to 2020 while the others are related to the country (1 country per entry).

```
gdp <- reshape(GDP, varying= 1960:2020, v.names = "GDPpercapita", timevar = "Year", times = 1960:2020, direction = "long")
```

However, I obtain the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , varying.i) : undefined columns selected
```

I tried to find where my error comes from with the documentation and looking in some forums, but I still can not find the problem.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I found that if I use `c("1960","2020")` instead, it works for these two columns.
Does it exist a simple, conventional, and efficient way to use all the values from 1960 to 2020 without writing the 65 columns individually?

Comment: Instead of `c("1960", "2020")`, use `as.character(1960:2020)`.

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I needed !

Comment: On Stack Overflow, indicate a question is solved by "accepting" an answer - click the checkmark by the answer near the vote arrows. Don't edit "solved" into the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `c("1960", "2020")`, use `as.character(1960:2020)`.